# Windows Service - read partial configuration file while service is running

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I am developing a Windows Service which uses setings from app.config - specifically settings inside <appsettings>.

I know that I can reference a file inside the app.config such as appsettings configSource="file.xml" but what I need is at some point the Service "re-reads" the combined app.config for setting changes.

When I start the service it reads the config file as it is at that point and does not pick up the changes.

Has anyone came across this before?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")` will reload the section, including any referenced source files.